# Detect point in css animation when user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am using [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations). I want to on click detect which part of the animation the user is at. Is it possible?

I am doing something like a game where a boy (div) is running back and forth. When the user clicks, I need to animate the boy falling, meaning change the class so a different animation can start. But I need to know if the boy is moving towards the left or right to use the right falling animation. How should I do this?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: How about switching between two different classes for moving to left and to right so you can check the current class at a given point of time..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate CSS classes for moving to left and to right instead of one so you can check the current class at a given point of time..

Following is a quick example i made using CSS transitions instead of animations.

HTML

```
<div id='boy'></div>
```

CSS

```
#boy{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  transition:all 5s;
}
#boy.right{
  left:90%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#boy").addClass("right");
  $("#boy").on("transitionend. webkitTransitionEnd",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('right');
});

$("#boy").on("click",function(){
  var position = ($(this).hasClass("right"))?"right":"left";
  alert(position);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqq4s/)

**Update**

Same thing using CSS animations (*Setup for webkit browsers*):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqq4s/3/)

You could also use single animation and do fancy mathematic stuff using the `elapsedTime` property of `animationiteration` event.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to do it is to set in the keyframes a property that indicates that.

I have sometimes used z-index, you can set z-index to 5 when moving to the right, and to 6 when moving to the left.

Usually, you can get a range of z-index values that have the same resulting layout.